# Set value for a parameter in app.yml in symfony

Tags: symfony1, propel

I'm using Symfony Propel. I want change my app.yml variable value inside a for loop.

My code is

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
$previousValue = sfConfig::get('app_url');
sfConfig::set('app_url', $previousValue+1);
echo sfConfig::get('app_url');
}
```

I have set default value for url = 0

When i run this i'm getting value as 1 but it should be 4. When i run the page again then it should end up with 8, run again then 16 and so on.
What am i doing wrong.please help me.

Answer (score 4):

When you use sfConfig::set() you are only setting this value for the current runtime. You are not permanently editing app.yml.

While technically it would be possible to edit YAML files with PHP, I would not suggest it, as it's overly complicated compared to other alternatives, and symfony caches the parsed YAML files anyway.

You are better off storing this kind of values in your database. A simple query will suffice to increment your value.

Also check my answer in a related question: [edit values in app.yml by backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299028/edit-values-in-app-yml-by-backend/7299412#7299412)

Answer (score 1):

**sfConfig [1](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfConfig)** is not the good way to store persistent data, use **sfStorage [2](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfStorage)** instead, else each time you request your page your value is reseted to your initial value.

Your example :

***app.yml***

```
  all:
   url: 0
```

***indexSuccess.php***

```
  for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    $previousValue = sfConfig::get('app_url');
    sfConfig::set('app_url', $previousValue+1);
    echo sfConfig::get('app_url');
  }
```

***Output :***

```
12345
```

But each time your relaunch it, you will have the same output.

**Ps:** When you declare or initialize a config value, don't forget to clean your cache *`(php symfony cc)`*

Comment: But I'm not sure what you exactly want to do, let me know, I can show you how use persistent storage or write your configuration (dangerous way...)

Comment: Thanks what i wanted is when i relaunch it should maintain it old value here 5 and should increment to 6

Comment: Then you need to use sfStorage instead to store your data and increment it and save it permanently. http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfStorage